# Why are my EF Code First pregenerated views having no effect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.3

I have ~300 DbSets in my context and the first query after app load (a FirstOrDefault() where on an indexed field) takes ~40 seconds.

To improve this, I am attempting to use pregenerated views in EF 4.3.1 Code First using the T4 template here:

http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/06/13/entity-framework-codefirst-view-generation-templates-on-visual-studio-code-gallery/

I compile it in, but I see no performance difference.  I was hoping/assuming it would help the painful slow startup I am experiencing, but no luck.

Should it help?  If not, what exactly are pregenerated views used for?  And, is there anything I *can* do to improve startup time?  Splitting my context up is painful to say the least.

Comment: There's something weird with pre-compiled views in ASP.NET. I've had the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that it actually seems to search for the pregenerated views **in the assembly where the first referenced entity is**, not in the assembly where the DbContext is.  See more discussion here: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/06/13/entity-framework-codefirst-view-generation-templates-on-visual-studio-code-gallery/#comment-76.

To work around this, I made up a new entity and put it in the context's assembly, and listed it as the first DbSet.  Now it picks it up, and works well (except that this is ridiculous).

Comment: This behavior exists with Database and Model First as well. My pre-generated views are compiled with the context in the same assembly. They are picked up in a console or windows service application, but not under IIS. I'm able to see it because I'm using a T4 to generate them, and have added log.

Comment: have the same problema but I don't understand the solution. I have an asseblby with my POCO entities and another assembly with my edmx. I need to créate an entity in my assembly that has the edmx? How I listed it as the first DBContext? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Certain ORM's like NHibernate and EF are simply slow to start up. Instead of trying to "fix" this slowness, I like to eliminate the problem by making sure IIS triggers this code whenever the app pool starts up. For this to fix the problem you must configure IIS to automatically start your app pool. This solution is only available to .NET 4 and IIS7.5 and newer.

You want to implement a class with `IProcessHostPreloadClient` which loads an `ObjectContext` and configure your application to use it by adding a serviceAutoStartProviders node to your web.config and setting startMode="AlwaysRunning" for your applications app pool.

Please refer to [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) for details.

Comment: That's a good solution, but I, for reasons painfully out of my control, am stuck on IIS6/32 bit Window Server 2003, so I have no way to use IProcessHostPreloadClient and the site recycles from out-of-memorys midday all the time...

Comment: Recyceling regularly isn't a problem. The approach simply makes sure the app pool starts up again, while the normal behaviour is that it doesn't start untill a call arrives.
The IIS6 would be a dealbreaker however. Is selfhosting in a windows service an option?

Comment: It is a problem -- a user is using the site, a recycle is triggered, his next request goes to the new app pool, and that takes forever, making it appear that the site is hung.