# how to pregenerate the view in the EF 5?

Tags: c#-4.0, view, entity-framework-5

I have a Project that use EF 5.0, is data base first. I would like to pregenerate the views, so I try to use this temaplate:

[Template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx)

However, how I have one library that has the edmx and the reposutory and I have another assembly with my POCO entities, so the library that implements my repository has a reference to the assembly that has the POCO entities. But this is a problema, and I read a solution by Scott Stafford:

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543990/why-are-my-ef-code-first-pregenerated-views-having-no-effect/12060962#12060962)

In this solution he says:

"To work around this, I made up a new entity and put it in the context's assembly, and listed it as the first DbSet. Now it picks it up, and works well (except that this is ridiculous)."

However, I don't know where to create a new entity. This new entity must by in my library the has the edmx or in the assembly that has the POCO entities? Is it not needed to modify the template .tt?

Thanks.